# Как перебрать, и получить все объекты из ArgIterator?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Си библиотека отдает список аргументов `va_list`, думаю что логично перебрать все это дело через [`ArgIterator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.argiterator?view=netframework-4.8).

У меня встал вопрос, как мне получить объект который отдается через `GetNextArg`, он же в свою очередь отдает структуру типа `TypedReference`, однако, мне не понятно что это за структура, и как мне ее использовать что бы заполнить массив с `object[]`.

```
private unsafe void LogCallback
(
    IntPtr data,
    LogLevel level,
    IntPtr logContextPtr,
    byte* fmt,
    RuntimeArgumentHandle args
)
{
    byte* tmpFmt = fmt;
    int sizeFmt = 0;

    while (0 != *tmpFmt)
    {
        tmpFmt++;
        sizeFmt++;
    }

    ArgIterator iterator = new ArgIterator(args);

    string format = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fmt, sizeFmt);

    List<object> objects = new List<object>();

    while (iterator.GetRemainingCount() != 0)
    {
        RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle = iterator.GetNextArgType();
        TypedReference current = iterator.GetNextArg();

        // objects.Add(current);
    }

    iterator.End();
}
```

Как узнать тип который содержится в аргументе, и записать его в коллекцию?